# overflow encountered: multipliation of exp() times erfc()

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I want to evaluate the following formula:

```
c = exp{x}*erfc{y}
```

(see definition of `x` and `y` in the code below.)

The problem is that x and y are getting quite large and I get very large values for `exp{x}` and very small values for `erfc(y)`.

```
import numpy as np
import scipy as sci
k = 5.7e-3
D = 1.53e-8
R = 1.5e-5
r = 1e-6

t = np.linspace(0.0,12,10)

x = (r/R)  +  (D/(R*R) - k)*t
y = (r/(2*np.sqrt(D*t))) + np.sqrt(D*t)/R

exp_x = np.exp(x)
erfc_y = sci.special.erfc(y)
print("x = \n{} ".format(x))
print("y = \n{}".format(y))

print("exp(x) = \n{}".format(exp_x))
print("erfc(y) = \n{}".format(erfc_y))

print("exp(x) * erfc(y)= \n{}".format(exp_x*erfc_y))
```

My Idea was to change the evaluation to

```
log{exp(x)*erfc(y)} = log{exp(x)} + log{erfc(y)} = x + log{erfc(y)}
```

afterward, I can calculate

```
exp(x + log{erfc(y)})
```

But here is the problem:
When I want to calculate

```
log{erfc(y)} = log{1 - erfc(y)}
```

I get a similar problem that erfc will be close to 1 and I will get precision problems.

Any ideas to solve my problem?

Comment: As a quick idea, you can apply the `log` approximation to a part of your sample data (given that the only point where you have `erfc(y)==0` is the first one)

Comment: Yes, I had the same idea. I will test this, when I have time. However, I was able to solve my problem with Mathematica. That's not the way I like to solve problems, but it works right now.

Comment: use `log1p(x)` for `log(1+x)`

Answer (score 1):

The solution of this problem was given by Cadena, in this article:

Cadena, F. (1989). *Numerical approach to solution of pollutant transport models using personal computers. Computers in Education,* 9(2), 34-6.

I could not obtain the article, but the solution is also given by

Lin, J. S., & Hildemann, L. M. (1995). *A nonsteady-state analytical model to predict gaseous emissions of volatile organic compounds from landfills. Journal of hazardous materials*, 40(3), 271-295.

Cadena proposed to approximate the complementary error function in terms of another exponential function with a negative power term. It reduces the high power raised by the original exponential function that causes overflow.

Suppose `W` is the multiplication that needs to be evaluated:

```
W=exp(y)*erfc(x)
```

`W` can be approximated as:

```
W = (a1*t+a2*t^2+a3*t^3+a4*t^4+a5*t^5)*exp(y-x^2), t=1/(1+p*x), if x >= 0

W = 2*exp(y)-(a1*t+a2*t^2+a3*t^3+a4*t^4+a5*t^5)*exp(y-|x|^2), t=1/(1+p*|x|), if x < 0
```

where

```
a1 = 0.254829592
a2 = -0.284496736
a3 = 1.42141741
a4 = -1.453152027
a5 = 1.061405429
p = 0.3275911
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `scipy.special.erfcx()` which gives `exp(x**2)*erfc(x)`.

Then you just implement `erfcx(x)*exp(x-x**2)` which again gives `erfc(x)*exp(x)`.

This of course works best if your arguments `x=y`.